# Dataframe binned averages, skip nan

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan, binning

I have a dataframe of the following structure which is simplified for the sake of this question:

```
Date      A    B 
2016/1/1  nan  nan
2016/1/2  nan  nan
2016/1/3  3    2
2016/1/4  4    1
2016/1/5  nan  nan
2016/1/6  6    8
2016/1/7  7    nan
2016/1/8  8    3
2016/1/9  9    5
```

What I wish to do is create a 3 day binned average, I can easily do this using

```
df = df.resample('3D', on='Date').mean()
```

However using this method the nan values are counted as zero values and they affect the mean value like so:

```
Date      A    B
2016/1/1  nan  nan
2016/1/2  nan  nan
2016/1/3  3    2
```

Using `df.resample('3D', on='Date').mean()`  returns:

```
Date      A  B
2016/1/3  1  2/3
```

Where as I wish to obtain:

```
Date      A  B
2016/1/3  3  2
```

Where the na values are ignored for the calculation.

According to the documentation on .mean() I should be able to skipna values as listed on the page:

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mean.html#pandas.Series.mean

However when I run the following:

```
df = df.resample('3D', on='Date').mean(skipna=True)
```

The following is returned:

```
UnsupportedFunctionCall: numpy operations are not valid with resample. Use .resample(...).mean() instead
```

How do I go about solving this error and producing the correct mean values that I desire?

Comment: I think there is some problem, because for `df1 = df.resample('3D', on='Date').mean()` I get `df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [3.0, 5.0, 8.0], 'B': [2.0, 4.5, 4.0]}, index=pd.to_datetime(['2016-01-01', '2016-01-04', '2016-01-07']))`

Comment: So all `NaN`s values are excluded from count of mean.

Comment: Yes that is correct, the count of the mean is affected by the NaN values so to exclude them is what I'm looking for. `Cumsum` and`cumcount` is something that looks to work but I'm not sure how to implement it on the single line with resample.

Comment: Hmmm, it is a bit different. I try check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need:

```
#mean works perfectly
df1 = df.resample('3D', on='Date').mean()
print (df1)
              A    B
Date                
2016-01-01  3.0  2.0
2016-01-04  5.0  4.5
2016-01-07  8.0  4.0
```

For `cumsum` and `cumcount` with omiting `NaN`s need [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.resample.Resampler.transform.html), also for `cumcount` is used trick count `1`s:

```
df[['A1','B1']] = df.resample('3D', on='Date').transform('cumsum')

df[['A2','B2']] = df[['A','B']].mask(df[['A','B']].notnull(), 1)
df[['A2','B2']] = df.resample('3D', on='Date')[['A2','B2']].transform('cumsum') - 1
print (df)
        Date    A    B    A1   B1   A2   B2
0 2016-01-01  NaN  NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
1 2016-01-02  NaN  NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2 2016-01-03  3.0  2.0   3.0  2.0  0.0  0.0
3 2016-01-04  4.0  1.0   4.0  1.0  0.0  0.0
4 2016-01-05  NaN  NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
5 2016-01-06  6.0  8.0  10.0  9.0  1.0  1.0
6 2016-01-07  7.0  NaN   7.0  NaN  0.0  NaN
7 2016-01-08  8.0  3.0  15.0  3.0  1.0  0.0
8 2016-01-09  9.0  5.0  24.0  8.0  2.0  1.0
```

Comment: Thank you for this, after reading your answer I double checked something with the original dataset I was reading in and the dataframe operations were being performed on the wrong dataframe. This has been corrected so thank you for the insight.

Comment: No problem, `cumsum` and `cumcount` was no easy implement ;) Good luck!